# How to create run configuration with Yarn instead of npm in WebStorm 2016.2.3

Tags: webstorm, yarnpkg

I used to work with npm via WebStorm. I usually just add a npm based run configuration in the right corner, like what described in [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

I recently tried Yarn and I'm trying to do similar thing like with npm, however I can't find the options. Is there any way to do this? Or I just need to wait for updates from JetBrains?

Comment: yarn will be supported in **2016.3** -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23737#comment=27-1669437 . Also : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23820

Comment: Got it. Guess I'll just stick to terminal now then. Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

yarn will be supported in **2016.3**

As stated in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23737#comment=27-1669437

> In WebStorm 2016.3 it will be possible to select yarn package instead of npm:
>
> - go to `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`
> - click ellipsis button next to Node.js interpreter to open "Node.js interpreters" dialog
>
> Also, installed yarn packages will be available in drop-down list for your convenience.
>
> Once yarn package set, all npm-related actions will use the specified yarn package.

[image]

Also check the [WEB-23820](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23820) ticket for "yarn tasks" support (side panel similar to NPM tasks one where you can see the tasks and execute them).

---

**UPDATE (2016-11-15)**
WebStorm 2016.3 was released yesterday. Both aforementioned tickets were implemented.

---

**UPDATE (2016-12-13)**
On Windows, if you install Yarn via `.msi` installer, the path would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn` -- IDE (PhpStorm 2016.3.1 in this case) detected it automatically.

[image]

Comment: WebStorm 2016.3 is not supporting yarn installed by homebrew now. I commented in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23737#comment=27-1669437&u=1477301084808&tab=Comments . Hope it will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: I don't know how to set yarn if it's installed globally on windows with exe method. When setting it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn` I got `Please specify npm/yarn package: cannot find "bin\npm-cli.js"`. Same with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin`. Going back to default `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm`

Comment: @rofrol No idea -- PhpStorm 2016.3.1 picked it up automatically -- I just had to choose another entry in that dropdown box -- IDE found it automatically -- http://postimg.org/image/gk8nead6v/

Comment: Yarn in installed globally on my machine, i also added yarn to WebStorm run configuration as  *node interpreter:* C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.cmd   *node parameters:* start   *working directory:* ...     Usually i open CMD in working directory and run *yarn start*, when i do Run from WebStorm with the yarn config from above, it shows first couple lines exactly the same as in CMD:  
yarn start v0.23.3
$ yarn install && webpack-dev-server --config ./buildScripts/webpack.js --env.mode debug 

but after that it does not do anything....  (in CMD next line is:  yarn install v0.23.3)