# Why 'yarn' does not run in WebStorm's terminal?

Tags: powershell, terminal, webstorm, yarnpkg

I run my project with `npm` in WebStorm terminal and it runs fine. But with `yarn` it gives this error (Yarn runs with CMD correctly):

[image]

**I searched that here and saw this answer:**

[How to create run configuration with Yarn instead of npm in WebStorm 2016.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256897/how-to-create-run-configuration-with-yarn-instead-of-npm-in-webstorm-2016-2-3)

But I have `yarn package` on my WebStorm. See the below image:

[image]

So I don't know what is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks. But why does it run with `npm` fine, while it needs to `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` for `yarn`?

Comment: `npm` is a `.cmd` (Windows Batch file). `yarn` seems to have both `.cmd` and `.ps1` files (PowerShell module). `.ps1` is used in PowerShell session while in CMD session (standard `cmd.exe` shell) the `.cmd` file will be used. Run `powershell.exe` session outside of the IDE (e.g. `Win+R` then `powershell`) and you _should_ see the same result. Or use `cmd.exe` inside WebStorm as your shell instead of `powershell`.

Comment: PowerShell's Execution Policy affects PowerShell files (`.ps1` etc) only. It does not affect `.exe`, `.bat` or `.cmd`.

Comment: Basically, in your current WebStorm's terminal (PowerShell) -- run `Get-Command npm` then run `Get-Command yarn` and see what files will be executed if you run `npm` and `yarn` commands. I bet for _yarn_ it will be `yarn.ps1` while _npm_ will have `npm.cmd`. Especially see the info from the `CommandType` column: "Application" for _npm_ and "ExternalScript" for _yarn_ . The issue you are having is not WebStorm, it's PowerShell (security config).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the complete explanations :)